# merging more than 2 data frames whilst assigning an identifier factor in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reduce

Take this very simple RWE, I want to know what package can be used to automatically assign a factor (preferable the data frame name) when we merge two or more data.frames

I have manually defined the factor in the example below and shown the desired output. But i want to automate it as I have over 100 tables to merge. Note that the headers within each df are constant, only the name itself changes

```
A <- 1:5
B <- 5:1

df1 <- data.frame(A,B)

A <- 2:6
B <- 6:2

df2 <- data.frame(A,B)

df1$ID <- rep("df1", 5)
df2$ID <- rep("df2", 5)

big_df <- rbind(df1,df2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your data.frame names follow a certain pattern like beginning with "df" followed by numbers and they are not inside a list but simply in your global environment, you can use the following:

```
library(data.table)
bigdf <- rbindlist(Filter(is.data.frame, mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\d+"))), id = "ID")
```

Without data.table, you could do it as follows:

```
lst <- Filter(is.data.frame, mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\d+")))
bigdf <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(df, id) transform(df, ID=id), lst, names(lst)))
```

Comment: Fantastic hack, i knew there must have been a simple way. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
library(dplyr)
cof_df <- bind_rows(df1, df2, .id="ID")
cof_df
   ID A B
1   1 1 5
2   1 2 4
3   1 3 3
4   1 4 2
5   1 5 1
6   2 2 6
7   2 3 5
8   2 4 4
9   2 5 3
10  2 6 2
```

And then:

```
cof_df$ID <- factor(cof_df$ID, 
                    levels = c(1,2),
                    labels = paste0("df", unique(cof_df$ID)))
```

does the recoding.

A similar result can be obtained by naming the arguments in `bind_rows`, as in

```
cof_df <- bind_rows(df1=df1, df2=df2, .id="ID")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution will be to use merge:

```
merged <- merge(df1, df2, all=TRUE, sort =FALSE)

> merged
   A B  ID
1  1 5 df1
2  2 4 df1
3  3 3 df1
4  4 2 df1
5  5 1 df1
6  2 6 df2
7  3 5 df2
8  4 4 df2
9  5 3 df2
10 6 2 df2
```